# org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entity.Foo.bars

Tags: java, json, spring-restcontroller

I have an Entity

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Foo implements Serializable {   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "foos_bars",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foos_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bars_id"))
    private List<Bar> bars;
    // getters and setters go here

}
```

my controller is

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
    public String home() {      
        return toJSON(fooService.findAllFoos());
    }

    public static String toJSON(Object object) 
    { 
        if ( object == null ){
        return "{}"; 
        } 
        try { 
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

           return mapper.writeValueAsString(object); 
           } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
      return "{}"; 
      } 

}
```

I get the exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entity.Foo.bars, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->.entity.Foo["bars"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097)
    at controller.HomeController.toJSON(HomeController.java:39)
    at controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entity.Foo.bars, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:572)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    ... 47 more
```

I searched and found this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628526/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-in-manytomany-relationship-desp/23632999#23632999), and tried that on

```
@JsonIgnore 
public List<Bar> getBars() {
    return bars;
}
```

but I only get id and title of Foo in json response not the Bars related to that Foo. any one please help.

### Update

```
public List<Foo> findAllFoos() {
        return fooRepository.findAll();
    }
```

and the repository is just simple

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: can you post the code for `fooService.findAllFoos()`?

Comment: I've added method in __Update__ section

Comment: aa.., could you also show the code of `fooRepository.findAll()`?

Comment: added that one as well

Comment: actually the implementation would be better :)). anyway, I assume that the implementation is only simple retrieval correct?